# Derivative of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

I am having trouble grasping the concept of derivatives in relation to linear transformations. If I have a function f(x)=Tx which is the linear transformations given by the matrix T. Then what is the derivative Df(x)?

Comment: Please search before asking.

Comment: The derivative can be thought of as the best linear approximation to a function.  So if a function $f$ is already linear, then the derivative $Df$ will just be that function $f$.

Comment: For a more general result, look up Euler's Homogeneous Function Theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative (or, better said, the *differential*) of a function $f:D\subseteq\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ **at the point $x_0\in D$** is, by definition, a linear transformation $L$ such that $$f(x_0 + x) = f(x_0) + Lx + o(x)$$ where $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x)}{\|x\|} = 0$$

In particular, if $f$ is a *linear* transformation, then at any point $x_0$, the derivative of $f$ is simply $f$ itself, which can be easily proven, since $o(x)$ then becomes a very very simple function.